# SSRS Date Formatting and European numbers

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I created a number of fields in order to sort out why I couldn't easily format my date field as a date (it is date in the database, but with FetchXML it seems to lose the formatting. I know this should be accomplished with nested formulas, but since I kept having errors, I wanted to understand where the problem was exactly.

Date is "CreatedOn" : dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss
I created a field called "SignUpLeft" with this expression:

=Left(Fields!createdon.Value,10)

I created another field, and I called this "Cdate":
=Format(CDate(Fields!SignDateLeft.Value),"dd/MM/yyyy")

I have my report sorting by the "Cdate" field, but it is sorting by the Day, rather than by the month (see pic below.)  I have changed the report attribute localization to "es-es".

What else can I do to get the date formatted correctly, in order to sort.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could add one more data column. This data will be used for sorting and will have date in this format YYYYMMDD, for example. So you could use it to sort data in CDate column. Of course, there is no need to display this new data.

Comment: That's a good workaround, thank you.  It must also mean that my field is formatted correctly as a date, if it correcly pulled out the year and months.  It's strange that basic date sorting needs a workaround like this.

Comment: I've had the same problem a couple of times. As far as I could see, it sorted dates as strings. Maybe there is a correct way for the issue, but I've never really bothered to find it.